# Using Multidex enabled True in Build file crash app with Null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I am building an social app and since I have many dependency I used multidex enable true in build file and similarly added on manifest file. But it give me null pointer exception error and app craashes.

But when I remove multidex , then app runs without any error ..Please help.

My whole  project is https://github.com/BlueYeti1881/myfirstapp
Here is the log cat error
[image]

and build gradle file is

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nepalpolice.hometuitionnepal"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 2
         multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

         lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/project.properties'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'allclasses-frame.html'
        }

    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    // Support libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'


    //maps and location





    // Firebase
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'




    // MVP
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp:3.1.0' // Plain MVP

    // Social
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'

    // Images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'





}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why did they downvote...it is real problem and I am looking for solution and cause of problem.

Comment: in your application class public class Application extends android.app.Application replace with  Application extends MultiDexApplication

Comment: Thanks you saved me..it worked.

Comment: Posted Releted Answer Bro................if It helps please accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After Enabling Multidex

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    public static final String TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ApplicationHelper.initDatabaseHelper(this);
        PostInteractor.getInstance(this).subscribeToNewPosts();
    }
}
```

> Replace With

```
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static final String TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ApplicationHelper.initDatabaseHelper(this);
        PostInteractor.getInstance(this).subscribeToNewPosts();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BirNepali any time sir

Comment: could you please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473906/app-crashes-with-null-pointer-exception-with-requires-access-fine-location-permi